# These Sensor permissions are normal or required user permission to use in app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

I just searching about that these sensor are normal or dangrous permission mean is there any requirement of getting user permission to use these type of Sensore
1.Type Accelerometer
2.Type Light sensor
3.Type Gravity

can anyone help

Comment: afaik there is no permission for sensors, you can just read data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No . you should declare them in the manifest but they don't need user permission

Comment: could you post "these" permissions lines, which should be placed in manifest?

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />

Comment: thats not permission, thats info that app is using feature. afaik it isn't mandatory to keep this line in manifest for handling sensors data